# MySQL nested selection

Tags: mysql, sql, database, psql

I am trying to figure out this question on a practice page online with the following tables:

**Question:**
For all cases in which the same customer rated the same product
more than once, and in some point in time gave it a lower rating
than before, return the customer name, the name of the product,
and the lowest star rating that was given.

I cant seem to figure out why this isnt correct - would anyone be able to help?

Comment: You need join conditions (switch to modern, explicit join syntax.) Also a GROUP BY is needed.

Comment: Can you add sample data please? I'm working on something for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have so far (without sample data):

```
SELECT
    Customer.customer_name,
    Product.product_name,
    MIN(Rating.rating_stars)
FROM Rating
JOIN Product ON Rating.prod_id = Product.prod_id
JOIN Customer ON Rating.cust_id = Customer.prod_id
GROUP BY Customer.customer_name, Product.product_name
HAVING COUNT(Product.prod_id) > 1
```

Comment: Great! That works!, on line seven, it should be Rating.cust_id = Customer.cust_id not prod_id

Comment: Where are you checking that the lower rating should be in the future? You are not even checking that the ratings should be different.

Comment: Glad this gets what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This query will return the minimum rating stars of a product that has been reviewed more than once by the same customer, with any of the newer ratings lower than an older rating:

```
SELECT
  r1.prod_id,
  r1.cust_id,
  MIN(r1.rating_star) AS min_rating
FROM
  rating r1 INNER JOIN rating r2
  ON r1.prod_id=r2.prod_id
     AND r1.cust_id=r2.cust_id
     AND r1.rating_date>r2.rating_date
     AND r1.rating_star<r2.rating_star
GROUP BY
  r1.prod_id,
  r1.cust_id
```

you can then join this query with products and customers table:

```
SELECT
  customer.customer_name,
  product.product_name,
  m.min_rating
FROM (
  SELECT
    r1.prod_id,
    r1.cust_id,
    MIN(r1.rating_star) AS min_rating
  FROM
    rating r1 INNER JOIN rating r2
    ON r1.prod_id=r2.prod_id
       AND r1.cust_id=r2.cust_id
       AND r1.rating_date>r2.rating_date
       AND r1.rating_star<r2.rating_star
  GROUP BY
    r1.prod_id,
    r1.cust_id) m
  INNER JOIN customer on m.cust_id = customer.cust_id
  INNER JOIN product ON m.product_id = product.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a few points:
You cant specify the tables in the FROM clause the sane way you specify attributes in the SELECT. You can only have a single table in the FROM, and one more for each Join you use.
    SELECT a, b, c FROM a; <----------fine
    SELECT a, b, c FROM a, b; <----not fine
    SELECT a, b, c FROM a JOIN b; <---fine

When it comes to the tables in the FROM/JOIN, you dont use "AS" to give them an alias, just the table name followed by the alias.

FROM atable a JOIN btable b; <--This assigns alias a to "atable" and b to "btable".

You also have to specify the common attribute that the tables are going to be joined on:

customer JOIN rating ON customer.cust_id = rating.cust_id;

As for the rest you can probably work out the correct WHERE clauses to use once you have the syntax down.